# JSF условное выражение

Tags: jsf

необходимо получаемое значение из поля проверить, если оно меньше 15, то выводит одно сообщение, иначе другое. Сравнить значение из поля и определенное число получается через equals. А вот с операторами <, <=, >, >= не получается.

```java
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{dashboardContext.context['tehprisRSO_ELCalc_maxCapacity'] eq 15}">
    <h:outputLabel for="calc_capacity" value="Значение"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, вдруг кому пригодится:
Note the importance of keyword based EL operators such as gt, ge, le and lt instead of >, >=, <= and < as angle brackets < and > are reserved characters in XML. See also this related Q&A: Error parsing XHTML: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
На русском:
Операторы >,>= and <,<= в JSF выглядят как gt, ge, le and lt

```java
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{dashboardContext.context['tehprisRSO_ELCalc_maxCapacity'] lt 15}">
    <h:outputLabel for="calc_capacity" value="Значение"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```